# Bitwise shift unsigned long on Arduino

Tags: c, arduino, bit-manipulation, long-integer, bit-shift

Why does the following not work on Arduino?

```
unsigned long test = 1 << 20;
```

I've tested the bit shifting using the following sketch.

```
void setup() {

  Serial.begin(9600);

  unsigned long test = 0;

  for(int i=0; i<32; i++)
  {
    test = 1 << i;
    Serial.print("i:");
    Serial.print(i);
    Serial.print(" dec:");
    Serial.println(test);
  }
}

void loop() {

}
```

Which gives me the following output:

```
i:0 dec:1
i:1 dec:2
i:2 dec:4
i:3 dec:8
i:4 dec:16
i:5 dec:32
i:6 dec:64
i:7 dec:128
i:8 dec:256
i:9 dec:512
i:10 dec:1024
i:11 dec:2048
i:12 dec:4096
i:13 dec:8192
i:14 dec:16384
i:15 dec:4294934528   <--- ???
i:16 dec:0            <--- ???
i:17 dec:0            <--- ???
i:18 dec:0            <--- ???
i:19 dec:0            <--- ???
i:20 dec:0            <--- ???
i:21 dec:0            <--- ???
i:22 dec:0            <--- ???
i:23 dec:0            <--- ???
i:24 dec:0            <--- ???
i:25 dec:0            <--- ???
i:26 dec:0            <--- ???
i:27 dec:0            <--- ???
i:28 dec:0            <--- ???
i:29 dec:0            <--- ???
i:30 dec:0            <--- ???
i:31 dec:0            <--- ???
```

What happens at bit 15 and ongoing??

Testing the whole code in Xcode gives me the expected output.

Comment: Because `1` is not `unsigned long`

Comment: Use `1UL` as the constant instead of `1`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`int` seems to be only 16 bit wide on your target machine.
`1` is an `int`, therefore shifting it by more than 15 bits invokes undefined behavour.  The solution is simple, you should use a `long` constant:

```
 unsigned long test = 1UL << 20;
```

The language you write in is not exactly C, but this solution should still be correct.

Incidentally, `1 << 40` invokes undefined behaviour if `int` is 32 bits.  Below is a simple test:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int a = 1, b = 40;

int main() {
    printf("1 << 40 = %d\n", 1 << 40);
    printf("1 << 40 = %d\n", 1 << 40);
    printf("1 << 40 = %d\n", 1 << 40);
    printf("%d << %d = %d\n", a, b, a << b);
}
```

On OS/X with `clang`, I get this output:

```
~/dev/stackoverflow > make t42
clang -O3 -Wall -o t42 t42.c
t42.c:6:32: warning: shift count >= width of type [-Wshift-count-overflow]
    printf("1 << 40 = %d\n", 1 << 40);
                               ^  ~~
t42.c:7:32: warning: shift count >= width of type [-Wshift-count-overflow]
    printf("1 << 40 = %d\n", 1 << 40);
                               ^  ~~
t42.c:8:32: warning: shift count >= width of type [-Wshift-count-overflow]
    printf("1 << 40 = %d\n", 1 << 40);
                               ^  ~~
3 warnings generated.
~/dev/stackoverflow > ./t42
1 << 40 = 1386850896
1 << 40 = 256
1 << 40 = 512
1 << 40 = 256
~/dev/stackoverflow > ./t42
1 << 40 = 1477618256
1 << 40 = 256
1 << 40 = 512
1 << 40 = 256
```

`clang` warns the programmer about the problem and insists on generating undefined behaviour, with consistently inconsistent output.  Amazing isn't it?  A good example of why one should never ignore compiler warnings

Comment: I did not say that, but the precise semantics of the Arduino development language (see http://arduino.cc/en/reference/homePage ) may not be exactly those of the C language.

Comment: you're right Arduino Language != C. unfortunately the Arduino Compiler used does not give me the warning you saw on OSX

Answer (score 1):

You are shifting `1` which is a 16-bit `int`. This works up to `16384` but `32768` is `-32768` or `0x8000` which is then sign-extended when assigned to `unsigned long` as `0xFFFF8000`, which is `4294934528`.

Comment: Your explanation is correct, but it should be noted that this behaviour cannot be relied upon.  Shifting an `int` by an amount that causes overflow or by an excessive amount invokes undefined behaviour.

Comment: @chqrlie I agree, and shifting so as to alter the sign bit is UB.

Comment: `1 << 40` definitely invokes undefined behaviour on OS/X.  `clang` makes a point of proving it...